# Cannot get "alias" command to work at al

Tags: command-line, alias, tcsh

Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I open a terminal, and type a simple alias command, but then it doesn't work:

```
~> alias ge='gedit &'
~> ge
ge: command not found
```

I've also tried adding aliases to .bashrc, .profile, .bash_aliases, all to no avail. What is most disturbing is that it doesn't work in command line.

Additional things, in response to comments:

```
    > alias ge='gedit &'
    > ge
    ge: Command not found.
    > alias
    >
    > echo $-
    Illegal variable name.
    > shopt -p expand_aliases
    shopt: Command not found.

    > . ~/.bashrc
    /usr/sbin/.: Permission denied.
    > source ~/.bashrc
    Illegal variable name.
```

Comment: Can you add the exact error message that you received?  The one shown is incomplete.

Comment: Could not reproduce.

Comment: @muru same here, either something is very wrong with his installation or he did a typo while typing his command

Comment: Running just `alias` should list all of your aliases (including several which come with Ubuntu out of the box). Does this give you output? Does it include your new `ge` in the output?

Comment: Please add output of `echo $-` and `shopt -p expand_aliases` to your question.

Comment: Thoth:~> alias ge='gedit &'
Thoth:~> ge
ge: Command not found.

Thoth:~> alias
Thoth:~> 

Thoth:~> echo $-
Illegal variable name.
Thoth:~> shopt -p expand_aliases
shopt: Command not found.

Answer (score 3):

You can also edit your `~/.tcshrc` file when using `tcsh` instead of `bash` to set a persistent alias:

```
echo 'alias ge "gedit &"' | tee -a ~/.tcshrc
```

Then, source the file and `ge` should open gedit:

```
source ~/.tcshrc
```

Comment: he tried running it from terminal, if that really didn't work i doubt it will work from .bashrc.

Comment: Still cannot get alias to work on command line. Here are additional bashrc problems:

Thoth:~> . ~/.bashrc
/usr/sbin/.: Permission denied.
Thoth:~> source ~/.bashrc
Illegal variable name.

Comment: @user3347308 That's cause you're in tcsh you crazy person:) You need to run /bin/bash before you go and try sourcing your bashrc file.

Answer (score 3):

Because you use `tcsh` instead of `bash`, your alias definition is wrong. Define an alias in `tcsh` via

```
alias ge gedit
```

or

```
alias ge 'gedit &'
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer: My shells were running tcsh. I had to switch this to bash. I realized this after accidentally just typing "bash" on the command line, and this made everything work (aliases, bashrc, etc.) All the problems above were due to simply not having bash running.

Comment: Yes, as we already said in the answers.